# C# - Showing error after adding a method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

whats wrong with this method? Im trying to add this method in a web service (.asmx) file. But its showing me error. After adding this, even other methods in that .asmx file showing same error.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string UpdateEvent(EventsClass es)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            string qr = "UPDATE Events SET Title = '" + es.Title +
                "', DateFrom = '" + es.DateFrom +
                "', DateTo = '" + es.DateTo +
                "', Location = '" + es.Location +
                "', DateTo = '" + es.DateTo +
                "', Status = '" + es.Status +
                "', Description = '" + es.Description +
                "', UpdateDate = '" + es.UpdateDate +
                "'  WHERE Id = '" + es.Id + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qr, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return "1";
    }
```

Error message is like this:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Error message returned in ajax post method:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
function(){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){n.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==n.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i…
```

Comment: An advice: Use a StringBuilder, with AddFormat on your queries commands, its more easy to build the code and clean to read too... ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you don't have `DBCS` configuration key in `Web.config` and you get exception in this line :

```
 string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ToString();
```

**Never** generate SQL query in this way. always use `SqlParameter` instead.
Using parameters helps prevent SQL Injection attacks

Comment: other methods also have same connection string.  and Web.config has DBCS configuration key.

Comment: @Jaber have you traced you code? in which line you have `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception??